# TypeError: isnull() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas

```
y = df.var3
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
tmp = pd.to_numeric(y_train, errors='coerce')
```

Running

```
mask = df.isnull(tmp)
```

Resulted in

> TypeError: isnull() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Looking at the shape of tmp:

```
>>> tmp.shape
(12731,)
```

there only seems to be 1 column.

On viewing the data in tmp, I found there to be 2 columns - the first had indices (in a jumbled order) and the second had the actual values. I thought that tmp had 2 columns, but it seems that any series type object always has an index column. Further, the shape also indicates only 1 column.

Slicing the series (using iloc) did not work either because of "Too many Indexers".

Am I trying to find the error where there is none?

Comment: `dataframe.isnull()` is a method that doesn't take any arguments (other than the instance, `self`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the number of columns of `tmp`.

The [`DataFrame.isnull()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) just *doesn't take arguments*. It's a method on a dataframe, so Python passes in the dataframe as the first `self` argument and you passed in a second, `tmp`.

You state that `tmp` is a Pandas `Series` object (`pandas.to_numeric()` could also have produced a numpy array, and you didn't specify what `train_test_split()` returns). If so, then just call:

```
mask = tmp.isnull()
```

because there is a [`Series.isnull()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) just like there is a `DataFrame.isnull()`.